# Multiplying polynomials with rational coefficients using NTL (C++ library)

Tags: ntl

I need to do polynomial multiplications over exact rationals (N/M where both N and M are arbitrary large integers). The NTL library is designed to quickly multiply polynomials over large integers. Any suggestions for on extending the capability to rationals?

My basic idea is to multiply through by the product of the denominators of each coefficient, pass to NTL, and then divide back out. Is there a more efficient way?